# Creating an AJAX Form for a Polymorphic Object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I am trying to create an AJAX form for a polymorphic associated model.

I created "Comments" which have a polymorphic association with all objects you can comment on (i.e. user profiles, organization profiles, events, etc).

I can currently add comments to objects using a form created by:

```
form_for [@commentable, @comment] do |f|
```

I am trying to make this form via Ajax but I keep getting errors.

I've tried at least ten different pieces of code, using remote_form_tag, remote_form_for, etc..with all different options, and nothing works. The comment does not get inserted into the database.

Specifically, I tried:

```
<% remote_form_for(:comment, :url => comments_path(@profile)) do |f| -%>
```

In my routes.rb, profile has many comments. And comments belongs to Profile. But when I submit the form nothing happens and the comment does not get posted to the database.

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

For your reference, here are my controllers. Comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  layout 'index'
  def index
    @commentable = find_commentable
    @comments = @commentable.comments
  end

  def show
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def create
    @commentable = find_commentable
    @comment = @commentable.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    if @comment.save
      responsetext = "<p><b>Comment: </b>" + @comment.content + "</p>"
      render :text => responsetext
    else
      responsetext = "error"
      render :text => responsetext
    end
  end

  def edit
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    if @comment.update_attributes(params[:comment])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated comment."
      redirect_to @comment
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed comment."
    redirect_to comments_url
  end

  private

  def find_commentable
    params.each do |name, value|
      if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
        return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
      end
    end
    nil
  end
end
```

Profile controller:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /profiles
  # GET /profiles.xml
  layout 'index'
  def index
    #@profile = Profile.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)

    @profile = current_user.profile
    @comment = Comment.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @profile }
    end
  end

  # GET /profiles/1
  # GET /profiles/1.xml
  def show
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    @commentable = @profile
    @comment = Comment.new(:commentable => @profile)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @profile }
    end
  end

  # GET /profiles/new
  # GET /profiles/new.xml
  def new
    @profile = Profile.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @profile }
    end
  end

  # GET /profiles/1/edit
  def edit
    #@profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    @profile = current_user.profile

  end

  # POST /profiles
  # POST /profiles.xml
  def create
    @profile = Profile.new(params[:profile])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Profile was successfully created.'
        format.html { redirect_to(@profile) }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @profile, :status => :created, :location => @profile }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @profile.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /profiles/1
  # PUT /profiles/1.xml
  def update
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.update_attributes(params[:profile])
        flash[:notice] = 'Profile was successfully updated.'
        format.html { redirect_to(@profile) }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @profile.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /profiles/1
  # DELETE /profiles/1.xml
  def destroy
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    @profile.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(profiles_url) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end
end
```

View:

```
<% remote_form_for([@commentable,@comment], :url => '/profiles/1/comments') do |f| -%>

<% #form_for [@commentable, @comment] do |f| %>



  <br /> 
<%= f.text_area :content %><br />

<%= submit_tag 'Post', :disable_with => 'Please wait...' %>

 <% end %>


    <h2>Comments</h2>
    <div id="comments">
    <% @profile.comments.each do |c| %>
      <div>
        <div style="float:left;width:50px">
        <%= image_tag c.user.profile.photo.url(:thumb) %>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;padding:5px">
        <b><%= link_to c.user.name, profile_path(c.user.profile) %></b>
        <%=h c.content %><br />
        <font style="color:grey"><%=h distance_of_time_in_words(Time.at(c.created_at.to_i).to_i,Time.now.to_i, include_seconds = true)  %> ago</font>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <% end %>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you paste the controller code? You need to have accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments in your profile model. In your controller you need to have

```
profile[:comments_attributes] = params[:comment]
profile.save
```

Comment: Where do I add that second piece of code? I posted my controllers...any help is appreciated because I still can't get it to work :\

Comment: You might want to do @commentable.save